# app specific keyboard

Tags: android

I don't want to replace the entire soft keyboard.  I want to add a Next/Prev buttons when the soft keyboard is deployed when a field in my WebView in the fashion that looks like the display on mylogin.yahoo.com

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElvDC.jpg

I have found this on github

https://github.com/chrisboyle/sgtpuzzles/blob/master/src/name/boyle/chris/sgtpuzzles/SmallKeyboard.java

which seems like a reasonable way to accomplish this functionality.

Is extending android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView be a reasonable way to go?

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, extend it is the best way to go. Wrap what you want to add. Create another keyboard and set it to that keyboard.